# How to declare pointer pointing to function which returns function pointer

Tags: c++, c

I have below code running fine and giving out expected result. 
**I have an additional query that how can I declare a pointer in my main function that holds the address of function A(funcA) ?**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


int funcB (void)
{
 printf("\n Now you are in function B \n ");

 printf ("\n this function is for returning code value no matter what\n");

 return -10;
}

int (*funcA(int x,int y)) (void)
{
 printf( " I am in function A \n ");
   static int sum;
   sum=x+y;
 printf ( "\n Sum is %d ",sum);
 return &funcB;
 }

int main ()

{

int (*fpb)(void);

int x;

fpb=funcA(10,15);

x=(*fpb)();   // Calling function B through fpb pointer

printf("\n Value stored in x for code is %d \n",x);

}
```

**Result** :

```
I am in function A

Sum is 25
Now you are in function B

this function is for returning code value no matter what

Value stored in x for code is -10
```

Comment: This Below works ,(Its nice to know there are different options for declaring pointer some of them pretty easy now as through auto keyword ). I am declaring fpa pointer pointing to function A.   Luckily I found that syntax for fpa and fpb happens to be same.                        int (*fpa) (void);
fpa=funcA(100,200);

Comment: Don't try to write multi-language source files. That is extremely hard work and any possible advantage versus writing single-language source files (various files rather than one) is very very minimal.

Answer (score 4):

> how can I declare a pointer in my main function that holds the address of function A(funcA) ?

1. You could write it directly (and uglily):

   `int (*(*fpa)(int,int)) (void) = &funcA;`
2. You could use [typedef](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typedef) to make it clear:

   `typedef int (*FPB)(void);`
   `typedef FPB (*FPA)(int, int);`
   `FPA fpa = &funcA;`
3. Because you tagged c++, you could use [auto specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) (since c++11) to make it direct and clear:

   `auto fpa = &funcA;`

Comment: @songyuanyao : I too agree , just to mention that it should be typedef int (FPB) (void);

Comment: @theartist33 `*` is necessary to make it a function pointer type. [demo](http://rextester.com/NOAVS60292).

Comment: @songyuanyao : it could be but w.r.t this original code I did not want funcB   to return any address it's simple int (fpb) (void) and I checked its working this way , with declaring it as you said with *funcB as typedef it didn't throw error but run time memory fault

Comment: @theartist33 I tried it [here](http://rextester.com/IYJC22326). Runtime fault might be other issues.

Comment: @theartist33 I see. You're using `fa *fpa`, it's fine.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax is grokky enough that it's best to use a typedef.  I'm not assuming C++11.  The `()`s go around `*NameOfType`:

```
typedef int (*funcBTypePointer) (void);

int main ()
{
    funcBTypePointer fpb;

    ...
}
```

I see that `funcA` is to return the address of funcB.  Here's how to do that:

```
funcBTypePointer funcA(int x,int y)
{
 printf( " I am in function A \n ");
 static int sum;
 sum=x+y;
 printf ( "\n Sum is %d ",sum);
 return funcB;
}
```

If you refer to a function without an argument list, you get a pointer to the function; `&` is not needed.

For more information on function pointers, see this tutorial:  http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/78-function-pointers/

Answer (score 2):

To figure out the type for a pointer to `funcA`, take the declaration of `funcA`:

```
int (*funcA(int x,int y)) (void)
```

and replace `funcA` with `(*fptr)`, so your declaration becomes

```
int (*(*fptr)(int x, int y))(void);
```

which reads as

```
        fptr                          -- fptr
       *fptr                          -- is a pointer
      (*fptr)(            )           -- to a function with
      (*fptr)(    x,      )           -- parameter x
      (*fptr)(int x,      )           --   is an int
      (*fptr)(int x,     y)           -- parameter y
      (*fptr)(int x, int y)           --   is an int
     *(*fptr)(int x, int y)           -- returning a pointer
    (*(*fptr)(int x, int y))(    )    -- to a function with
    (*(*fptr)(int x, int y))(void)    -- no parameters
int (*(*fptr)(int x, int y))(void);   -- returning int
```

You'd assign it as

```
fptr = funcA;
```

and call it as

```
int x = (*(*fptr)(a,b))();
```

Note that while some of us<sup>1</sup> find this kind of declaration *perfectly transparent*, most C programmers don't obsess over declaration syntax to this level and prefer to hide most of that complexity behind typedefs:

```
typedef int fb(void);
typedef fb *fa(int x, int y);

fa *fptr = funcA;
```

However, that declaration doesn't really tell you how to *use* `fptr` in an expression, whereas

```
int (*(*fptr)(int x, int y))(void);
```

is pretty unambiguous:

```
int x = (*(*fptr)(a,b))();
```

---

<sup>1.  I will cheerfully admit I'm an outlier in this regard; I once wrote some code that did pretty much what the `fptr` call above does (that is, call multiple functions through pointers in a single expression) and thought it was crystal-clear.  My coworkers quickly reminded me that I'm weird and insisted I break those into separate statements.</sup>

Comment: I tried to use below as you wrote above but it's throwing error **too many arguments ** while compiling `int (*(*fpa)(int,int))(void)=NULL;` `int t=(*(*fpa)(10,30))(void);` .

Comment: @theartist33: Derp.  Sorry, I left the `void` keyword in the function *call*, which is where the error is coming from; it should be `int t = (*(*fpa)(10,30))();`. That's what I get for not testing what I write.  I'll fix my answer.

Answer (score 1):

First rule of declaring "pointers to function" is "use a `typedef`".  You will be grateful when you come back in two weeks time, and try to work out what the hell is going on.

```
typedef void (*pfuncB_t)();  // (void) is a C-compatability hack.  Use () in C++.
```

so funcA's declaration becomes a lot easier to read:

```
pfuncB_t funcA(int x, int y);
```

... and declaring a type for a pointer to `funcA` is also easy.

```
typedef pfuncB_t (*pfuncA_t)(int, int);
```

and you can use it like:

```
pfuncA_t globalA = &funcA;   // You don't need the address-of, but it is legal.
```

Answer (score 1):

> How do I declare a pointer that can hold a pointer to `funcA`?

Unless you're very brave (and I'm too lazy to be that brave), you use a `typedef` for the pointer to `FuncB` type:

```
typedef int (*FunctionReturningInt)(void);
```

Now, `funcA` is a function returning a `FunctionReturningInt`:

```
extern FunctionReturningInt funcA(int x, int y);
```

To create a pointer to that:

```
FunctionReturningInt (*funcA_ptr)(int x, int y) = funcA;
```

Comment: That is the "Yes, Minister" meaning of "brave".  See http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?YesMinisterCourageValue

Answer (score 1):

Use a few `typedef`s

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int funcB(void) {
    printf("Now you are in function B\n");
    printf("this function is for returning code value no matter what\n");
    return -10;
}

int (*funcA(int x,int y)) (void) {
    printf("I am in function A\n");
    static int sum;
    sum = x + y;
    printf("Sum is %d\n", sum);
    return &funcB;
}

// typedefs to make life easier    
typedef int (ta)(void);
typedef ta *(tb)(int, int); // use previous typedef'd ta

int main(void) {
    int x, y;
    ta *fpb;
    tb *fpa;

    fpb = funcA(10, 15);
    fpa = funcA;
    x = fpb();   // Calling function B through fpb pointer
    y = fpa(10, 15)(); // calling function B through pointer to function A

    printf("Value stored in x for code is %d\n", x);
    printf("Value stored in y for code is %d\n", y);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is also worth mentioning that you can also use `std::function` (c++11). However, this is not a function pointer, but rather a wrapper that can hold any callable object. This is a more heavier approach compared to simple pointers.

If function pointers are enough for your case and you don't need to manage a lot of functions then I would definitely recommend to use function pointers.

(http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <functional>


int funcB()
{
  printf("\n Now you are in function B \n ");
  printf("\n this function is for returning code value no matter what\n");
  return -10;
}

std::function<int(void)> funcA(int x, int y)
{
  printf(" I am in function A \n ");
  static int sum;
  sum = x + y;
  printf("\n Sum is %d ", sum);
  return funcB;
}

int main()
{
  std::function<std::function<int(void)>(int, int)> func_a = funcA;
  std::function<int(void)> func_b = func_a(10, 15);
  int x = func_b();

  printf("\n Value stored in x for code is %d \n", x);

  return 0;
}
```